# Is there a generalized %>% dplyr operator

Tags: r, hadoop, dplyr

Completely explorative question:

I was wondering if there was an operator similar to %>% but that take one input (any data), but has multiple outputs so that to apply different "process paths". This would be usefull for hadoop distributed calculations where reading operations may take a long time.

So lets imagine that this operator has suffixes like %>1%, %>2%, %>3% (so here we would have 3 output paths. Lets image that we have data stored somewhere in the HDFS:

```
      %>1% process_1
data  %>2% process_2
      %>3% process_3
```

The result would be that we have read the data only once.

Thank you,
Samy

Comment: Have you looked at [`magrittr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/index.html)?

Comment: And perhaps specifically the `%T>%` operator?

Comment: @Sam perhaps the `invoke` function in the **purrr** package does what you are looking for, eg., `c(process_1, process_2, process_3) %>% invoke(data)`